# Review Audit making obvious failure on Duplicate flag

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today I was presented following First post for review:

[The post I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420386/reading-net-stack-trace).

This posts ask about .NET stack trace offsets, an issue that has come up many times before... for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305244/what-do-the-n-values-mean-at-the-end-of-a-method-name-in-a-stack-trace). That seems to be literally the same question.

So I did was what I thought would be obvious... I flagged it "Duplicate" and lo and behold, I was presented with a review audit fail:

<kbd>[image: Fail]</kbd>

Turns out the question I flagged got lots of upvotes but does that necessarily mean the question is good?

Probably, this post here is also a duplicate as the review auditing system seems far from perfect but still, this seems really extreme, or am I missing something?

Comment: Pro Tip: Always check the source question before making your final decision. If you had you would have seen the upvotes, the fact it has already been accepted and the original question date (which was over 4 weeks ago). Usually a combination of these factors is a dead giveaway that it's a review audit and then treat it as such.

Comment: Obvious, really?, to a automated system that goes off various criteria to simulate an audit, think that's a bit optimistic.

Comment: I understand... but that kind of defeats the purpose of the review system I would think. It should be possible to judge each question on its merits without being influenced by others/other factors. In most cases the collective will probably be right but if everybody seems to have collectively lost the ability to search something before they make a call then the whole system breaks down (voting and reviewing)...

Comment: Put it this way the audit is more helpful then it isn't. If it flags up poor review decisions but occasionally misses the mark then the good out-weights the bad so just take it on the chin and move on.

Comment: @Lankymart and if everybody starts checking posts they need to review in another window than the whole system becomes useless. I do not care about the notice I got, but I like to think that reporting it might contribute to improvements in the future. Anyway ...

Comment: FWIW audits were recently redesigned to [avoid similar "fake failures" when _voting_ (not flagging) to close as dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770/165773)

Comment: @Kris You said: "if everybody starts checking posts they need to review in another window than the whole system becomes useless." No, it doesn't become useless. The system was put into place primarily to deal with folks who were just clicking through without reading. They were destroying the value of the review system. These folks are quickly caught by the current audit system. This has immense usefulness.

Comment: @Louis I think if people who are just clicking through get into the habit of opening the question in another tab and looking at the votes, they will not be much deterred by the audit system at all...

Comment: @eddie_cat If they are opening links in other tabs to read the post so that they make an **informed choice** (the choice does not need to be sophisticated, just informed), then they are no longer just clicking through without reading. A huge problem has been eliminated.

Comment: @Louis I am talking about people who could just open the tab to make sure it's not an audit. If they see a bunch of upvotes or that the post is deleted, they will know what the action to take not to fail is. If it's not an obvious audit they can click "looks good" without ever reading the post because they will know it's not an audit and it doesn't matter. Dunno how likely it is that people would do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encountering a common problem with the audits. The audits are selected algorithmically rather than manually, and as far as I can tell, a large number of upvotes  can cause a question to be selected as a "known good" question for audits. As suggested in the comments, using the link to view the original question can usually give these away so you can pass the audit. In this case, I think the action you took was perfectly fair so you have to just accept the failed audit and move on. **It happens to everyone that does reviews.** If you really feel the need to dispute this, I believe you can contact a moderator and they can prevent the post from becoming an audit for someone else, but I don't know if they can remove the failure from your history.

As a side note, some comments have suggested that the ability to view the original question and tell that it's an audit defeats the purpose of audits, but I disagree. The audits are in place to keep people from mindlessly clicking through the audits, so if someone takes the time to view the original question and base their decision on that, I think that's okay. Searching for "Review Audits" on MSO will show you a LOT of discussion about this and various proposals for how to make the audit system a little more fair.

In response to your questions at the end of your post: No, a lot of upvotes does not necessarily mean the question is good or not a duplicate. It's an unfortunate downside to the audit system that I agree needs improvement, but it's not a terrible system either. If you pass most of the audits most of the time, you won't be banned, and there's no hit on your rep either, which I think is a good thing.

### TL;DR

I think you took the correct action, and the occasional failure of an audit is fairly common among reviewers. As long as it's rare, you shouldn't see any adverse effects so you can just forget about it and move on.

Comment: I wasn't too worried about this kind of thing happening in itself. It has sporadically happend to me before that the algorithms involved seemed to miss something. So far however, I have not experienced ill effects (such as a e.g. ban) and probably 99+ % of my flags are deemed helpful. However, given todays experience I was actually wondering if the system for judging an audit could not somehow happen in a deferred way, letting others judge its fairness (e.g. when a high vote question still gets flagged). But then again, that might be an audit of an audit... Turtles all the way down :)

Comment: As I mentioned, there is a TON of discussion about having some kind of formal dispute process for audits all over meta. I would like to see some kind of system put in place for this, but until that happens, "unfair" failures like this will happen sometimes and from what I can gather from other discussions, there isn't much to do but move on to the next.