# Stop look and listen when flagging exact duplicate answer

Tags: feature-request, flags, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, duplicate-answers

I'd like to start by referencing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271239/1467396) post where the OP failed an audit by flagging a QUESTION as duplicate.  The accepted answer there is "I think the action you took was perfectly fair so you have to just accept the failed audit and move on. It happens to everyone that does reviews."  I have had a very similar experience when flagging a duplicate ANSWER.  In the short term, the same answer applies to my case, but I would like to propose a possible solution. But first, some background...

I was just reviewing "First Posts" and was presented with [this review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/8565327).  It's a good answer, right? I thought so, but I don't want to be a "robo-reviewer", so I took a closer look.  I noticed that the question was asked just over 2 weeks ago, so I wanted to know if this answer [added something new](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275058/1467396).

I headed over to the original question and immediately spotted it--another answer that is EXACTLY the same as this one; word for word and even the formatting is the same!  The only difference is that this other answer came 11 minutes after the question was asked and it was from a fairly high-rep user, whereas the one in my queue was posted just a few minutes ago from a brand new user.  It looked like plagiarism to me, so I flagged it for moderator attention.

That was the wrong thing to do, apparently.  SO slapped my hand and told me it was a high quality post and I should have left it as is.

Now, this is a good live-and-learn experience and after going through it and reading through many of the meta posts on the topic, I think I'll be more able to spot these tests for what they are: tests.

But there's something that bothers me about it.  What if it WASN'T a test?  What if this WAS a new user who actually DID make an exact copy? Wouldn't my not-flagging it be irresponsible?  Isn't this auditing just training me to allow such shenanigans?

Ideally, reviewers should be checking for this sort of thing.  I would like to propose two possible solutions:

1. When you flag an answer, you get to choose between "spam", "rude or abusive", "not an answer" and "in need of moderator intervention".  SO could add the option "Plagiarism" which would require you to post a link to the source material you suspect has been copied.  In the review-audit, if you use that flag and point it to the original answer, then you should pass the audit. (Side note: this proposal would also address [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266236/1467396) question.)
2. Don't show the user or post time in the review.  I actually don't really like this solution very much, but it would probably be much easier to implement and is better than nothing. Essentially, I was "tricked" into thinking that this was a NEW, and DUPLICATE post, when in reality it was not.  Don't show me that it was a new user that posted it 5 min ago when that's not the case.  No information is better than misinformation.  This could apply to just the "first post" queue (since first posts imply the user has no rep) but frankly, I don't think we should be considering a user's rep when deciding the quality of their questions/answers, anyway.  We are supposed to be looking at the quality of the current POST, not [user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297211/1467396).

Comment: I don't see the 11 minute later duplicate answer that you refer to.

Comment: See, the thing with your 1: The people who _do_ check should, ideally, _notice that the answer they're reviewing doesn't actually appear on the page._ You see the one that it "copied," but did you see the duplicate at all on the question? That right there would tell you it's not _actually_ a plagiarized answer, but an audit. Did you think to check that when you checked your post? Or did you just see the "original" and didn't think to make sure the "copy" was on the page? I'm not saying you're suggestion is bad- Just that with only 4 answers, you could have avoided the fail with more attention.

Comment: @davidism: you wouldn't because it isn't actually there.  The review-audit made it look like I was reviewing a new answer that was, in fact, the old one.

Comment: @PhatWrat Are you saying that because the post was anonymized for review purposes, you thought it was a duplicate answer?  But clicking on the link in a review post takes you to the actual post, at which point you would have immediately noticed that it was a good, not duplicate post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu PhatWrat actually _did_ go to the question in this case. The problem was they didn't pay enough attention to notice their "duplicate answer" they were reviewing wasn't actually there, and instead thought the review was a duplicate answer of the linked answer.

Comment: @Kendra: oh... I thought the answer wouldn't appear on the page until it passed the "first post" review process.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Kendra I was going to mention that the link would have taken them to the "real" non-deleted answer that had tons of upvotes.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No review queue currently keeps posts from being posted to the site. I'm not sure if Triage, at the moment, is hiding them from the front page like they should, but First Posts and Late Answers will _always_ already be posted when you see them in review. Now that you know that, you shouldn't get tripped up by this case again.

Comment: @Kendra I think that's the source of confusion for this post, and is answer-worthy.

Comment: If you use the link on the review-page, it will lead you straight to the post on the site. So, you know it's a "known bad"-audit if you don't land at an answer. And you can be fairly sure it's a "known good"-audit if it sends you to an upvoted post. What's easier?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm not sure I could expand that out into a good answer. If you or someone else wants to turn it into one, go for it. :)

Comment: looks like the same issue as described in [Audit: High quality post problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266379/839601)

Comment: @gnat Yes, that's a great duplicate target.